# how gulp serve related to sharepoint spfx webpart

Tags: sharepoint-online, spfx, spfx-webparts, gulp

I have created the sample spfx solution and uploaded it into the app catalog and i have added it to the site page. if I am changing in the local code and if I run the gulp serve the actual changes are reflecting in the SharePoint pages also. how is this possible. anyone please explain the process.

Answer (score 3):

You probably ran the gulp tasks for bundling and packaging without the "--ship" flag at the end, so it still connects to your localhost after deployment

You can find some guidance here:
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/web-parts/get-started/hosting-webpart-from-office-365-cdn#prepare-web-part-assets-to-deploy

Answer (score 0):

If you open the `<your-webpart-guid>.manifest.json` from the `\dist` folder, you will notice that the **internalModuleBaseUrls** property in the **loaderConfig** entry still refers to your local computer:

```
"internalModuleBaseUrls": [
  "https://`your-local-machine-name`:4321/"
]
```

You can find more detail [here](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/web-parts/get-started/serve-your-web-part-in-a-sharepoint-page#preview-the-web-part-on-a-sharepoint-page).